# Determine a field on the real line that has the following characteristics:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, stability-in-odes

Determine a field on the real line that has the following characteristics:

**a)** At point $-1$ the field is canceled and is a singular repulsive point.

**b)** In the origin the field is canceled and it is a singular attractor point.

**c)** At point $1$ the field is canceled and is a singular repulsive point.

I just can think of fields for each of the subsections. Any hint of what could be a field that accomplish all tree?

Comment: I just corrected it. Thanks! It makes sense now?

Comment: I removed the "fields" tag from your post; that is usually reserved for algebraic fields not vector fields.  I replaced it with the "vector-field" and "stability-in-odes" tags which seem more germane to your topic.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the vector field

$X(x) = x^3 - x, \; x \in \Bbb R; \tag 1$

we have

$X(-1) = X(0) = X(1) = 0, \tag 2$

that is, each of $-1$, $0$, $1$ is a critical point, or as our OP Sofia Contreras phrases it, a point where "the field is cancelled.". Note that

$x < -1 \Longrightarrow X(x) < 0, \tag 3$

$-1 < x < 0 \Longrightarrow X(x) > 0, \tag 4$

$0 < x < 1 \Longrightarrow X(x) < 0, \tag 5$

$x > 1 \Longrightarrow X(x) > 0; \tag 6$

it follows that the motion of a particle moving under the influence of the vector field $X(x)$, that is, the motion of which satisfies the ordinary differential equation

$\dot x = X(x) = x^3 - x, \tag 7$

is in the direction of *decreasing* $x$ under conditions (3) and (5), and in the direction of *increasing* $x$ in cases (4) and (6), since the direction of motion is given by the sign of $\dot x$, which indicates whether $x(t)$ becomes greater or lesser with $t$; these observations are sufficient to infer that $-1$ and $1$ are repulsive points, whereas $0$ is an attractive fixed point of the flow of $X(x)$

We may also analyze the stability/instability of the three points $-1$, $0$, $1$ by examining the first derivative of $X(x)$ at each of these $x$-values; indeed we find

$X'(x) = 3x^2 - 1, \tag 8$

whence

$X'(-1) = X'(1) = 2, \tag 9$

and

$X'(0) = -1; \tag{10}$

since

$X'(-1) = X'(1) > 0, \tag{11}$

the standard theory shows that $-1$ and $1$ are repellors, whilst

$X'(0) < 0 \tag{12}$

indicates $0$ is an attractive, in accord with our previous discussion.